# Can not connect to Spark Thrift Server using JDBC, keeps using Hive

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, azure-hdinsight

I am using Azure HDInsight and want to connect to Thrift Server using JDBC in similar way as described here: [Thrift JDBC/ODBC Server](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-thrift-server.html).

However it always connects to Hive and not Spark Thrift Server. While they both look similar and I can query data, I want to exploit Spark execution engine  as I am using mainly Spark2 and sometimes need JDBC connection. Spark engine is also probably faster than Hive/TEZ.

Connection string looks like this:

```
jdbc:hive2://hdinsight-name.azurehdinsight.net:443/default;ssl=true?hive.server2.transport.mode=http;hive.server2.thrift.http.path=/hive2
```

Drivers tried:

```
1. maven:/org.spark-project.hive:hive-jdbc:1.2.1.spark2
2. maven:/org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc
```

Update: Looks like Spark Thrift Server is not exposed to public: [Ports used in HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-port-settings-for-services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to connect to Spark Thrift Server from JDBC client with following workaround.

Spark Thrift Server is running on port 10002, which is not publicly accessible as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-port-settings-for-services) in Azure HDInsight docs. Thus, here is alternative way to connect to Spark SQL from local JDBC client.

**Background:**

I connected to cluster head node via SSH.

```
ssh user@cluster-name-ssh.azurehdinsight.net
```

From here, I was able to connect to Spark Thrift Server using Beeline client.

```
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://localhost:10002/;transportMode=http'
```

With Beeline, I can run SQL queries using Spark engine.

**Solution:**

So I set up SSH port forwarding in my local machine (forward local port 10002 to cluster head node)

```
  ssh -L 10002:localhost:10002 user@cluster-name-ssh.azurehdinsight.net
```

Now, I can use this port in JDBC client to connect to Spark SQL.

```
jdbc:hive2://localhost:10002/;transportMode=http
```

With that, you can use Spark SQL from your local JDBC client.